# How can look for the features of random forest tree/decision treee?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am using python to create a decision tree classifier. I want to see the features NAME that I have used from the classier. Here is the code

```
In [3]: my_forest.feature_importances_
Out[3]: 
array([ 0.09546647,  0.210264  ,  0.31768782,  0.24191602,  0.05580487,
        0.04318897,  0.03567185])
```

I can find out 7 features but name is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Transform your data into a dictionary using:

```
dv = DictVectorizer()
newX = dv.fit_transform(all_data)
```

Now use the newX instead of X for training and testing. Then, you can do

```
tree.export_graphviz(classifier_used, feature_names=dv.get_feature_names(), out_file='graph.dot')
```

This will help you visualize all the features.

Comment: Is there a easy way without visualizing, I am only looking for the feature 'names'!